# Using of MIN and COUNT together

Tags: sql, count, min, minimum

I have this table:

CALLS

```
| Number | User_id | Duration | Date | Call_type |
  46534       2         65     1-1-13     5
  46535       3         55     1-1-13     4
  46537       1         47     1-2-13     5
  46538       7         87     3-4-13     7
```

And I need to know the date or dates where I have the minimum quantity of phone calls.

How can I do that?

Comment: What SQL dialect? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Top 1 WITH TIES Number
    COUNT(Number),
    MIN(Date)
FROM <tablename>
GROUP BY Number
ORDER BY COUNT(Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Group on the date and sort on the count, that will put the dates with the fewest calls at the top:

```
select Date, count(*) as Calls
from CALLS
group by Date
order by count(*)
```